# Invoking an instance method from a REST service method

Tags: java, swing, rest

I have a REST service accepting POST requests. Is there any way I can trigger a method inside my running swing GUI from that service? I want to make it possible to refresh the GUI table of posted data after every POST request is made. Is there any event handling mechanism for doing this?

REST service code:

```
@POST
@Consumes({OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response createServiceRegistration(
        @PathParam("serviceProviderId") final String serviceProviderId , 
        final ServiceRegistration aServiceRegistration
    ) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    try 
    {
        ServiceRegistration newServiceRegistration = OrchestratorAdaptorManager.createServiceRegistration(httpServletRequest, aServiceRegistration, serviceProviderId);
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("ETag", OrchestratorAdaptorManager.getETagFromServiceRegistration(newServiceRegistration));

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //       Accessing and writing registration data to database 
        //      
        try
        {
            System.out.println("establishing database connection");
            Registration registration = new Registration();
            registration.createConnection();
            registration.insertRegistration(aServiceRegistration.getService().toString(), aServiceRegistration.getTitle(), aServiceRegistration.getLabel());
            registration.shutdown();                    
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error inserting ServiceRegistration to the database", exc);                 
        }               
        //
        //        Disconnected from the base
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

        return Response.created(newServiceRegistration.getAbout()).entity(aServiceRegistration).build();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new WebApplicationException(e);
    }


    //Trigger changes in GUI here :/
}
```

Class which I used to update the table every 10 seconds:

```
class CheckServices extends TimerTask
{
    DefaultTableModel model;
    protected CheckServices(DefaultTableModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {           
            Registration reg = new Registration();
            try 
            {
                reg.createConnection();
                ServiceRegistration[] sr = reg.selectRegistrations();
                reg.shutdown();
                System.out.println("Adding Registration Resources");

                int rows = model.getRowCount();
                for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    model.removeRow(0);
                }

                for(ServiceRegistration srItem : sr)
                {
                     System.out.println("--> " + srItem.getTitle());
                     Object[] row = { false , srItem.getService().toString(), srItem.getTitle(), srItem.getLabel()};            
                     model.addRow(row);
                }               
            } 
            catch (URISyntaxException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }       
}
```

Comment: Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread. Your code that updates the TableModel should be wrapped in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to place the code on the EDT. Don't use a loop to delete individual rows from the model. This will generate multiple repaint() requests for each row deleted. Instead just use the `DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(0)` method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I fixed that. I am using EventQueue.invokeLater(), is there any difference between that and the class you mentioned? Also, the problem I had was trivial, I just passed the GUI instance reference to the service which invokes repaint() method inside GUI, refreshing the table. Is that the correct way of doing this? I have been reading about EDT, but I am pretty new at this.

Comment: `I am using EventQueue.invokeLater(), is there any difference..` no, the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() just invokes that method. `I just passed the GUI instance reference to the service which invokes repaint() method inside GUI, refreshing the table.` no, you don't need to invoke repaint(). Whenever you update the TableModel the model will notify the table of the change and the table will repaint() itself automatically. `I have been reading about EDT` you can also check out the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).